# How to integrate configuration files from a config service in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration

I am currently running a rails application and a SpringBoot configuration service in the same local network. Is it possible to configure rails to use the config files provided by the service in Springboot?

More specifically I am looking to fetch the database connection and user data via the service and let rails connect to a remote database.

The service provides theses files via http as json or yml.

Thank you.

Edit: Solved it by using a bash script with wget to pull and assemble config files manually via container scripts that are executed before each deploy.

Comment: Does it need to by dynamic or can you simply download the configuration when you deploy your app?

Comment: It has to get the configuration every time the app is restarted. No changing on the fly.

Comment: Then when you restart the app, get the configuration, no need to do that inside your app!

Comment: It is deployed on OpenShift and DevOps don't want to alter the container each time they have to tweak the config. They will have access to a git repo where the config data is stored and that should be integrated into the rails application. So each time they restart the pod a new config will be pulled.